Discord JS Bot will not work, constantly returns that an attachment is not an image
I'm trying to make a discord bot that takes a user's attachment in a certain channel, upload the attachment to Imgur using the imgur js package, and then return the newly uploaded link back to the user.
The bot runs fine and then whenever I send an image into the channel, it returns that the file attached is not an image even though it is.
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const imgur = require('imgur');
const fs = require('fs');
const config = require('./config')

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });

imgur.setClientId(config.imgurId);

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Bot online`);
})

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {

    // Ignore messages sent by the bot itself
    if (message.author.id === client.user.id) return;

    if (message.channel.id != config.evidenceChannel) {
        await message.channel.send("Please use the correct channel to upload evidence")
    } else {
        if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
            message.attachments.forEach(async (attachment) => {
                // Check if the attachment is an image
                if (attachment.name.toLowerCase().endsWith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.'))) {
                    try {
                        const imgUrl = attachment.url;
                        const title = message.content || "Untitled";
    
                        // Determining the title of the
                        const uploadedImage = await imgur.uploadUrl(imgUrl, { title: title });
    
                        await message.channel.send("Image uploaded to Imgur:");
                        await message.channel.send(uploadedImage.link);
    
                        // Store the link of the url that was created
                        fs.appendFileSync("links.txt", `${title} - ${uploadedImage.link}\n`);
                    } catch (e) {
                        comsole.log(`${e}`);
                    }
                } else {
                    await message.channel.send("The file attached is not an image.");
                }
            });
        }
    }

});
client.login(config.TOKEN);

This is my current code, maybe I've missed something but I can't see it.
